# Display particular folder list view

Tags: view, sharepoint-2013, directory, caml

I have document library in which several folders, in one of them I have sub-folder that I need to display in custom view. So, position of that folder is like **Doc.Library** > **Folder2** > **Internet**.
I found several examples how to display Folder instead of whole Library in custom view, with help of CAML query in SPD2013.

Here is what I have in my custom view:

```
<Where>
    <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name="FileRef"/>
        <Value Type="Text">Internet</Value>
    </Contains>
</Where>
```

Now comes part which gives me problem, with this query, I get blank page, no documents are visible. If I put **Folder2** instead of **Internet** I see documents but I see all documents of Folder2 folder, which I don't need.
So, my question is how can I manage to show Internet folder only?

I tried several other options, instead of Text to put Lookup, FileLeafRef instead of FileRef, etc. but none were successful.

Comment: I would suggest to delete this question since it is a duplicated from this one https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210588/display-particular-folder-list-view

Answer (score 2):

With minor changes I solved problem.
Instead of FileRef I put FileDirRef. For View I added Scope="RecursiveAll" and for Value I put relative address.

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef"/>
        <Value Type='Text'>/sites/sitename/subsitename/DocLibraryName/folderName/SubFolderName</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```